# What does @ before a parameter in a function call means in Pascal

Tags: sdl, pascal, freepascal

I have stumbled into multiple examples of Pascal code (FPC compiler mode) where the '@' symbol is sometimes used before the name of a parameter in a function/procedure call, and I couldn't find what this means. Sometimes i even saw it being used with a variable which had not been declared yet. For instance :

```
procedure displayImage ( var window , image : PSDL_SURFACE );
    var destination_rect : TSDL_RECT ;
BEGIN
    {Setting of the x,y,w and h parameters of the destination_rect variable}
    SDL_BlitSurface (image , NIL , window , @destination_rect);
    SDL_Flip (window)
END;
```

```
SDL_PollEvent (@event); //The event variable hasn't been declared or initialized prior to this, yet this seems to work
if event.type_ = SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN then
    {Do stuff}
if event.type_ = SDL_QUITEV then
    {Quit program}
```

I suppose this might be a SDL quirk, since every time I encountered this it was in a SDL related function, but I couldn't find anything about it.

Comment: [This thing](http://www.math.uni-leipzig.de/pool/tuts/FreePascal/ref/node9.html#SECTION03650000000000000000)?

Comment: It's not an SDL thing. `@` is the *address operator*, which means it's passing the address of the variable, which means the function can modify the contents. You might try reading the [documentation](http://www.math.uni-leipzig.de/pool/tuts/FreePascal/ref/node9.html#SECTION03650000000000000000).

Comment: FWIW, `destination_rect` is declared prior to its use, it is the parameter. I don't have the full code for your second snippet, but I assume that `event` is a parameter too. In Pascal and many other languages, parameters are similar to local variables. I think you should heed Ken's advice and read the documentation or a good book on Pascal, e.g. Essential Pascal, a free online book.

Comment: Oh, and if you have probems with pointers, read my article about them: [Addressing pointers](http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-pointers.html).

Comment: event has been declared, otherwise it would not compile

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Borland like Pascals, the @ is the address-of operator, similar to & in C/C++.

Additionally, the own Free Pascal dialects (fpc and objfpc) require a @ in places where in TP/Delphi you can just pass the function/method

This was added to disambiguate a corner case where a function/method returns a procedure/method type with the same signature.

It is one of the things in mode objfpc that hurt compatibility and don't add much (since it only solves a quite contrived corner case), which is why I avoid these modes if I can, and use {$mode delphi} as much as possible.